# Dual band routers

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, internet-connection, bandwidth, dual-band

I’ll keep it short and simple. I have a dual band router.

I want to know if having both the bands on reduces the network speed? As in if I switch the 5GHz network off... will I get a better speed on the 2.4GHz network?

Answer (score 3):

Each one of those is a separate transmission medium, with separate transceivers. Thus the bandwidth values for them aren't summed up together. If you turn off either one you'll have less total bandwidth

Comment: Meaning that both have different values and turning one off doesn’t change the values of the other ?

Comment: yes. It's like 2 separate cables that don't relate to each other